# Which of these Boost Asio multithread tcp server examples is more correct?

Tags: c++

Have seen two different examples of this and what/which one is correct?

1. `std::vector<std::thread> threads;`
2. `boost::asio::io_context io_context{(int)threads};`

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
auto count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
for (unsigned int n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
    threads.emplace_back([&] { io_context->run(); });
}

for (auto &thread : threads) {
    if (thread.joinable())
        thread.join();
}
```

```
auto threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
boost::asio::io_context io_context{(int)threads};

std::vector<std::thread> v;
v.reserve(threads - 1);
for(auto i = threads - 1; i > 0; --i)
    v.emplace_back(
        [&io_context]
        {
            io_context.run();
        });
io_context.run();
```

Comment: The two code samples look essentially identical to me?

Comment: In the second one, one still needs to call join on the threads. Otherwise fairly identical except, second one creates one thread less which isn't really important.

Comment: The first variant doesn't `reserve` and allocates one thread more while the main thread just keeps waiting – second variant doesn't join. First variant has clearer names, `io_context` is a bad name in both cases (same as a type). I personally would go with *this* variant (somehow mixing both...): `std::vector<std::thread> threads; size_t count = ...; boost::asio::io_context context(count); --count; threads.reserve(count); while(count--) { threads.emplace_back(...); } context.run(); for(auto& t : threads) { ... }`

Comment: I consider uniform initialisation flawed (consider `SomeContainer c{7, 2.0}` with same constructors as pre-C++11 `std::vector` – adding a `std::initializer_list` constructor later on is a breaking change(!) – mandatory double braces as `... c{{7, 2.0}}` would have avoided this problem) which is (in my eyes) the true error in both variants. I personally always go with classic initialisation (like `std::vector<int>(7, 2)` vs. `std::vector<int>({7, 2});`), which can get essential especially in template meta programming...